# Заливка в Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Как изменить цвет под графиком, нижнюю часть (сделать заливку) в Chart.js ?[image: график]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure) надо установить значение `fill` в `true` и задать `bacgroundColor` нужный цвет.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgb(13, 152, 186)'
            ],
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```